Find DNS Records from name server
I want to publish a new website on an existing domain. I am working for a client, who gave me access to the domain website.
The domain settings only have name servers, and I don't know where to find the DNS records to update them. Is there a way to check where my DNS records are?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!
